# Idiomatic way to return multiple errors or handle them accordingly

Tags: go, error-handling

I have this code and I don't like the way it feels not to mention `golint` doesn't like it with `error should be the last type when returning multiple items (golint)`. To explain this code:

- I want to leave it to the user to decide whether they care about any of the errors returned
- Particularly in this code the Audio file is sometimes not needed or required and it can be ignored
- Video and Outputfile are likely always going to be required for whatever the user is doing

I am open to refactoring this in any way (be it breaking it apart, moving things around, etc.) Is there a more *idiomatic* way in Go to accomplish something like this?

```
// Download will download the audio and video files to a particular path
func (r *RedditVideo) Download() (outputVideoFileName string, outputAudioFileName string, errVideo error, errAudio error) {
    outputVideoFile, errVideo := downloadTemporaryFile(
        r.VideoURL,
        TemporaryVideoFilePrefix,
    )
    if errVideo == nil {
        outputVideoFileName = outputVideoFile.Name()
    }

    outputAudioFile, errAudio := downloadTemporaryFile(
        r.AudioURL,
        TemporaryAudioFilePrefix,
    )
    if errAudio == nil {
        outputAudioFileName = outputAudioFile.Name()
    }

    return outputVideoFileName, outputAudioFileName, errVideo, errAudio
}
```

Similarly I found myself using this same pattern again later in code:

```js
// SetFiles sets up all of the input files and the output file
func (l *localVideo) SetFiles(inputVideoFilePath string, inputAudioFilePath string, outputVideoFilePath string) (errVideo error, errAudio error, errOutputVideo error) {
 // Set input video file
 l.inputVideoFile, errVideo = os.Open(inputVideoFilePath)
 if errVideo != nil {
  return
 }
 if errVideo = l.inputVideoFile.Close(); errVideo != nil {
  return
 }

 // Set output video file
 l.outputVideoFile, errOutputVideo = os.Create(outputVideoFilePath)
 if errOutputVideo != nil {
  return
 }
 if errOutputVideo = l.outputVideoFile.Close(); errOutputVideo != nil {
  return
 }

 // IMPORTANT! Set input audio file LAST incase it is nil
 l.inputAudioFile, errAudio = os.Open(inputAudioFilePath)
 if errAudio != nil {
  return
 }
 if errAudio = l.inputAudioFile.Close(); errVideo != nil {
  return
 }

 return
}
```

This time in this code again some of the same is true like above:

- We care that the Video and Output are set and may or may not care about the Audio
- There are multiple errors are there to handle that are left up to the user

Comment: Returning an audio file and a video file and an audio error and a video error very, very strongly indicates that this function is doing too much and should be two functions.

Comment: Particularly given the note that "Audio file is sometimes not needed or required and it can be ignored" I would say this just needs to be refactored into two functions which each do one thing rather than one function that does two things.

Comment: I would try to go with typed errors, or just create `DownloadVideo` and `DownloadAudio`

Comment: Which actually would mean that we download a file both times, check that we can open it both times and return an error both times. Sounds to me like it could be refactored to a single method.

Comment: With the additional code this is definitely a case for some serious refactoring. Functions should do *one thing* and do it well. That's not just idiomatic in Go, that's universally good practice in any language.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback; I admittedly created this post without thinking of how I would refactor it but my objective here would be to basically hide all the details, give me a URL and a place you would like to store the video, and I will download the video, audio if it exists, and try to write out to the file you specified. I would like to keep all those details behind the scenes - these posts have inspired me to give this design a second glance more indepth than finding crafty or "idiomatic" ways to return multiple errors

Comment: Downloading a file which is then discarded by the caller seems incredibly wasteful. I'm on the split-the-function train.

Comment: we use errors.Wrap and errors.Wrapf a lot

Answer (score 0):

What you can see quite a bit in the standard library are specific functions which wrap more generic non-exported functions. See the commented code below.

```
// download is a rather generic function
// and probably you can refactor downloadTemporaryFile
// so that even this function is not needed any more.
func (r *RedditVideo) download(prefix, url string) (filename string, error error) {
    outputFile, err := downloadTemporaryFile(
        r.VideoURL,
        prefix,
    )

    if err == nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Error while download: %s", err)
    }

    return outputFile.Name(), nil
}

// DownloadVideo wraps download, handing over the values specific
// to the video download
func (r *RedditVideo) DownloadVideo() (filename string, averror error) {
    return r.download(TemporaryVideoFilePrefix, r.VideoURL)
}

// DownloadAudio wraps download, handing over the values specific
// to the audio download
func (r *RedditVideo) DownloadAudio() (filename string, averror error) {
    return r.download(TemporaryAudioFilePrefix, r.AudioURL)
}

func main() {

    r := RedditVideo{
        VideoURL: os.Args[1],
        AudioURL: os.Args[2],
    }

    var videoerror, audioerror error
    var videofileName, audiofileName string

    if videofileName, videoerror = r.DownloadVideo(); videoerror != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got an error downloading the video")
    }

    if audiofileName, audioerror = r.DownloadAudio(); audioerror != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got an error downloading the audio")
    }

    fmt.Printf("Video:\t%s\nAudio:\t%s", videofileName, audiofileName)
}
```

This way, it is obvious from which download the returned error stems from.

Answer (score 0):

From https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go:

> Go code uses error values to indicate an abnormal state.

In your situation, Audio is optional and Video is required. Therefore only Video download should return error:

```
// Download will download the audio and video files to a particular path
// empty outputAudioFileName indicates inability to download Audio File
func (r *RedditVideo) Download() (outputVideoFileName string, outputAudioFileName string, err error) {
    outputVideoFile, err := downloadTemporaryFile(
        r.VideoURL,
        TemporaryVideoFilePrefix,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err 
    }
    outputVideoFileName := outputVideoFile.Name()
    outputAudioFile, errAudio := downloadTemporaryFile(
        r.AudioURL,
        TemporaryAudioFilePrefix,
    )
    outputAudioFileName := ""
    if errAudio == nil {
        outputAudioFileName = outputAudioFile.Name()
    } else {
        // Log error, it is still important to fix it
    }

    return outputVideoFileName, outputAudioFileName, nil
}
```

Rule of thumb - any code that can generate abnormal state should have in next line:

```
    if err != nil {
        return funcResult, err
    }
```

Comment: i have seen this a lot:

if err = doSomething(); err != nil {\n return err\n }